# shouldn't this date format fail validation?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am using `strptime()` to create a datetime object to validate the string format. The format should be `mmddyy` for example `112023`

Using this format code `"%m%d%y` for the 2 digit day, month, and year works as expected

```
file_name_date = "112023"
print(bool(datetime.strptime(file_name_date, "%m%d%y")))
print(datetime.strptime(file_name_date, "%m%d%y"))
```

output:

```
True
2023-11-20 00:00:00
```

but this format code `"%m%d%Y` also works. I would expect this one to fail the format since it is asking for the 4 digit year, but instead it's treating it as JAN 1 2023

```
file_name_date = "112023"
print(bool(datetime.strptime(file_name_date, "%m%d%Y")))
print(datetime.strptime(file_name_date, "%m%d%Y"))
```

output:

```
True
2023-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: The string does literally say 1/1/2023 (adding in slashes). So it's not wrong, just that your string conforms to two formats.

Comment: @JNevill yes but %m and %d are asking for 2 digits not 1.

Comment: That's for printing back out. For reading in, the padding is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check python documentation on [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). They have *Note* associated to them. Note 9 says:

> When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, %S, %j, %U, %W, and %V.

Which is why, it assumes your string `112023` day and month don't have a leading zero and it parses it as 1-1-2023 (%m-%d-%Y).